# routing conflict with assets in rails - only on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, routes, asset-pipeline

In my routes, I define a global category with some ID to load dynamic content:

```
get "/:global_category/:id" => "pages#index"
```

The route is placed **on the bottom** of routes.rb.
All easy and no problem, at least on development.
Now I also load some webfonts via CSS into my app and when I' on production, I get the following exception whenever my fonts are loaded:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

The affected URL is:
*http://www.example.com/assets/Sansation_Bold-webfont.woff*

I load fonts that are located in /assets/fonts in a sass file like this:

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'ApolloASM'
  src: url('ApolloASM-webfont.eot')
  src: url('ApolloASM-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('ApolloASM-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),url('ApolloASM-webfont.woff') format('woff'),url('ApolloASM-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),url('ApolloASM-webfont.svg#apollo_asmregular') format('svg')
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal
```

There is obviously a conflict with my routes and the assets pipeline.
Only on production (I deploy on **heroku**) I can reproduce this so I tried to modify my production.rb but after looking into the docu (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) I still don't really know what to do.

I also tried to precompile assets.

That does not seem to be the cause of the issue and also my Fonts are all loaded correctly!
Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the sass helper "font-url":

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'ApolloASM'
  src: font-url('ApolloASM-webfont.eot')
  src: font-url('ApolloASM-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), font-url('ApolloASM-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),font-url('ApolloASM-webfont.woff') format('woff'),font-url('ApolloASM-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),font-url('ApolloASM-webfont.svg#apollo_asmregular') format('svg')
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal
```

no need to pre-compile or add anything in the production.rb or application.rb file

make sure that fonts are all stored in the /app/assets/fonts directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a route like this is that it will be matched by a load of other paths on your system.  Eg, "/users/123" will be interpreted as `pages#index params={:global_category => "users", :id => 123}`, whereas you might have been expecting it to go to `users#show params={:id => 123}`.

Catchall routes like this need to go near the bottom of your routes.rb file, so that they don't "steal" the paths from the other routes: the routes are tested in the order in which the appear in the file.

Comment: Yes I know about routing priorities and that route is already on the bottom of the routes rb :( So I'm wondering why I still get that error and only on production.

Comment: Does the asset definitely exist at that location in the filesystem (relative to your app's public folder)?  Maybe your server isn't finding the asset and so falling back to routes.rb.

Comment: hmmm. those are all fonts, located in /assets/fonts - I load them via a sass file like this "src: url('ApolloASM-webfont.eot')" - do I need to use a url tag here maybe? question still remains why it only happens on production :-/

Comment: The assets are served from a different location in production and development.  is there a file at `<rails folder>/public/assets/Sansation_Bold-webfont.woff` ?

Comment: Oh you might need to do the asset precompile too.

Comment: No success after pre compiling :/ I can also see in the deployment log that precompiling works. Also the font-file **IS** loaded and is there and works. No idea why this exception pops up.